# explicit "switch to mobile theme" link with Theme Key

Tags: theming, uri, navigation, theme-negotiation

I'm using Theme Key https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey to switch automatically between themes dependent on browser and/or OS id. 
Now I would like to allow the user to explicitly switch to or from to one or the other theme by clicking a link too. The`Persistant URL` https://www.drupal.org/project/purl module might be helpful for this but how exactly can I go about implementing this?

**EDIT 1**

I followed **Answer 1**, added `drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.cookie');` into the already existing `function marinelli_preprocess_page(&$vars)` in my `template.php`.

I setup two `ThemeKey` rules like:

```
system:cookie = "theme=marinelli" THEME [Marinelli]
```

and

```
system:cookie = "theme=skeleton" THEME [Skeleton]
```

and 
added following html to my page:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="$.cookie('theme', 'marinelli')">Switch to Marinelli</a> <a href="#" onclick="$.cookie('theme', 'skeleton')">Switch to Skeleton</a></p>
```

But clicking the links, doesn't do anything, seems like I might be missing something or it might not quite work this way because `href="#"` doesn't actually reload the page if that was the actual idea...?

Comment: Are you going to use different domains or subdomains for each theme?  If not, and you have any caching enabled, you could run into problems where the wrong theme gets cached unintentionally.

Comment: @PatrickRyan there was no intention to use different urls - if I have to, I can just manually link to one or the other but then the usage of `Theme Key` becomes obsolete, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, using theme key or not - you will most definitely have caching problems if you have theme switching ability for anonymous users and have page caching enabled.  Your options are to disallow theme switching for anonymous users or disable page caching.  If either of those are an option I can post an answer for you.

Comment: @PatrickRyan I will be able to disable caching. Thanks for providing an answer! Alternatively, will I be able to use the Devel module and set "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load"? Will that resolve the caching issue too?

Comment: You definitely don't want to do that on a production site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it to work with cache you can use the Mobile Cache module, at least as inspiration to make your own module using the library Mobile Detect.

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/acy76/1962696

But you need to modify this line in the module and must look like this

```
_mobile_cache_add_query_string('device=' . $data['device'] . '&theme=' . $_COOKIE['theme']);
```

Notice that the idea is add the theme name to the cache

I'm using Authcache and Filecache

Thanks @PatrickRyan

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to nest each theme switching rule inside another rule using

`system:cookie` `=` `theme=theme1`

```
     Theme switching rule here
```

`system:cookie` `=` `theme=theme2`

```
     Another theme switching rule here
```

You will need to set up your theme switching links to create a cookie using your method of choice, PHP or jquery.cookie

An example using jquery.cookie could be something like:

**template.php**:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.cookie');
}
```

**Your theme switching links**:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery.cookie('theme', 'theme1'); location.reload(); return false;">Switch to Theme1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery.cookie('theme', 'theme2'); location.reload(); return false;">Switch to Theme2</a>
```

Keep in mind that this is not page caching friendly.  If you want this to work for anonymous users, you will need to disable page caching.

Comment: Is it enough to disable caching under `admin/config/development/performance`?

Comment: Is there a global `template.php` that gets processed in any case (for any theme)? Or shall the `drupal_add_library()` go into each's `page.tpl.php` template e.g.?

Comment: To answer my own question, I found this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7 - a default `page.tpl.php` is located in `modules/system/page.tpl.php` and I believe `THEMENAME_preprocess_page` should be `template_preprocess_page` instead, is this right @PatrickRyan?

Comment: Yes that is how you disable the built in caching.  All themes have a `template.php` file usually at `sites/all/themes/yourtheme/template.php`.  This is where the above function goes, just replace THEMENAME with your themes machine name.

Comment: Please see **EDIT 1** above

Comment: Correct, the page needs to reload.  You can add replace the link with whatever you want or you can add `location.reload()` to your onclick.  Example edited above.